# Julia LibPQ against openssl v3

Tags: postgresql, openssl, julia, libpq

I have an issue about the title.
My env is
ubuntu22
openssl v3.0.2
julia v1.9.4
PostgreSQL v16

then libPQ looks like request libssl.so.1.1
`Precompiling LibPQ [194296ae-ab2e-5f79-8cd4-7183a0a5a0d1] ERROR: LoadError: InitError: could not load library "/home/onoke/.julia/artifacts/b89b9ae1e6ebbe1fe6561c490a5b1e1285d12a6e/lib/libpq.so" libssl.so.1.1: cannot open the file: there is not such a file`

I will put the lib due to this message ,but I wonder LibPQ is not going to correspond to libssl.so.3?

Thx.

Comment: You are using a `libpq.so` binary that was built with OpenSSL 1.1. Either install a `libpq.so` that is built against OpenSSL 3 or build PostgreSQL from source.

Comment: Thx Laurenz, yes I supporsed to install libpq.so that was the version of Openssl3. I compiled it from the source, then linked it to julia artifacts: in my case ~/.julia/artifacts/<hash code>/lib/libpq.so -> <openssl3 libpq.so>. Of course it worked fine. My point was LibPQ.jl would not have a plant to upgrade? Anyhow thank you for your reply.

Comment: You'd have to ask the people who write and package the Julia connector to PostgreSQL.